# Changing the pattern-matching call depending on value of radio button in Dash

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am creating a Dash app that allows the user to either enter URLS to be screenshot and then analyzed or the user can upload their own images. I am trying to get the main app.py file right so the inputs can be sent to one of three different functions (one that only takes screenshots of the websites they listed, one that uses robots to search for similar websites and then takes screenshots of those to be analyzed, or just having the user upload their own images to be analyzed). Note that once they hit the "Submit" button, that the relevant inputs (the email, company name, and URL/images) will be passed off to an rq job. I understand how to do this part, so for the example, we can just print out the relevant inputs in the web app just to confirm that we have the right inputs.

The idea for the UI is that it would first have a section to put your email (and other info), and then start with radio buttons for each screenshot option. Then depending on the user's preference of the inputs they want to provide, they would either be shown a place for them to enter the different URLs or a place to upload their images ([See image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUscU.png)).

It seems that [pattern-matching](https://dash.plotly.com/pattern-matching-callbacks) would be useful for them to add more URLs, but I can't quite figure out how to allow different types of inputs using it. Here's what I have so far:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State, MATCH, ALL


app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/dZVMbK.css'])
server = app.server

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div([
        html.H6("""E-mail address:"""),
        dcc.Input(
            id='rec-email',
            placeholder="youremail@domain.com",
            size=30
        ),
        html.H6("""Company Name:"""),
        dcc.Input(
            id='company-name',
            size=30
        ),
    ]),
    html.Div([
        dcc.RadioItems(
            id='radio-option',
            options=[
                {'label': "Only analyze these websites", 'value': 'exact_sites'},
                {'label': "Allow robot to analyze additional related websites", 'value': 'robot_sites'},
                {'label': "I want to upload my own images", 'value': 'upload_images'}
            ],
            value='exact_sites'
        ),
        ]),
    html.Div(id='website-methods-output')
    ])

@app.callback(
    Output('website-method', 'children'),
    [Input('radio-option', 'value')],
    [State('rec-email', 'value'),
    State('company-name', 'value')]
)

def display_inputs(radio_option, email, company):
    if radio_option=="upload_images":
        return html.Div([
            id='inputs-start',
            dcc.Upload(
                id='input-upload',
                children=html.Div([
                    'Drag and Drop or ',
                    html.A('Select Image to be Analyzed.')
                    ]),
                    style={
                        'width': '30%',
                        'height': '60px',
                        'lineHeight': '60px',
                        'borderWidth': '1px',
                        'borderStyle': 'dashed',
                        'borderRadius': '5px',
                        'textAlign': 'center',
                        'margin': '10px'
                        },
                        # Allow multiple files to be uploaded
                        multiple=False # Maybe change to True?
                ),
            children=[],
            html.Button("Add Image", id="add-image", n_clicks=0)
            ])

    else:
        return html.Div([
            id='inputs-start'
            dcc.Input(
                placeholder='www.website.com'
                ),
            children=[],
            html.Button("Add URL", id="add-url", n_clicks=0)
        ])



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you have an input for each of the possible radio button options, but only show the one that's selected? You can set up pattern-matching callbacks for all the inputs, and use just one at a time. Perhaps a change to the radio button selection would not only change which options are shown/hidden, but clear all of them as well, so you can be sure to accept only entries in the correct one.

Edit:
This really goes beyond the scope of a single question, so I'm leaving out a lot of details here to keep from writing an entire Dash app. I hope this helps. These are some possible function definitions for each of the different types of callbacks I mentioned in the comments.

#### Show/hide sections

```py
@app.callback(
    Output('inputs-container', 'children'),
    [Input('radio-option', 'value')])
def callback_func_show_hide(radio_selection):
    # Add the function logic
    pass
```

#### Add a new input for a section

```py
@app.callback(
    Output('inputs-type-1-container', 'children'),
    [Input('add-input-1', 'n_clicks')]
    [State('inputs-type-1-container', 'children')])
def callback_func_add_input_1(add_input_click, previous_children):
    # Add the function logic. You'll need the previous_children in 
    # order to append new inputs
    pass
```

#### Use inputs from a section

```py
@app.callback(
    Output('some-output', 'children'),
    [Input({'type': 'upload-1', 'index': dash.dependencies.ALL}, 'value')])
def callback_func_process_upload_1(uploaded_data_list):
    # Add the function logic. Use uploaded_data_list to process everything.
    # Output can be whatever you want to let the user know the task is done
    pass
```

Comment: could you show an example? Sorry, I am still new to dash. Thanks.

Comment: I can show an example of some part, but I'm not sure which part you'd like me to show. There are 7 callbacks involved: one to show/hide the sections and reset the values; 3 to add more inputs, one for each section; and 3 to consume the values, one for each section.

Comment: Honestly whatever you can show would be much appreciated. Maybe one example of each type?

Comment: Added some examples. There's really too much going on here for me to answer comprehensively, but I hope this helps.